# IO Operations in Conduit?

Tags: haskell, conduit

This is probably a pretty obscure case, but please bear with me.

I'm writing a web crawler that needs to download webpages and save them to local disk.  Meanwhile, being a crawler, it needs to find the hyperlinks on each page and download those linked pages as well.

Right now I'm looking at the first sample code given on [this page](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/http-conduit).  I'm trying to write a conduit of this type:

```
processLink :: Conduit S.ByteString IO S.ByteString
```

And then I will replace this line in the sample code:

```
responseBody res $$+- sinkFile "foo.txt"
```

with this line:

```
responseBody res $= processLinks $$+ sinkFile
```

So what I'm trying to do is to implement a conduit called processLink, which processes a ByteString, extracks links from them, and then pass the original ByteString along to sinkFile so that the page can be saved.  Then I can call functions on those links recursively to download those linked pages.

However, since processLink is a pure function, it seems like I can't do any IO operations inside processLink, and therefore cannot do the things I need like downloading those linked pages.  Or can I?  What could I do to get around this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright I figured it out.... I think what I need is just liftIO lol.  Sorry I'm kinda new to Haskell :P